# How to make Kali Linux lmv partition bootable again in macOS?

Tags: lvm, macos

I want to get my macOS partition back, it is hidden somewhere in this lvm partition.

After installing Kali Linux with lvm on my MacBook Pro I no longer see my macOS partition. Grub also didn't boot the Kali Linux so I had to used a bootable usb to display the partition table:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, it looks like you let the Kali installer overwrite your macOS partition. At least some of your macOS data is now overwritten and gone.

If you were not using FileVault encryption, it might be possible to recover some files that are not already overwritten by scanning the disk using appropriate data recovery software (if your macOS was High Sierra or newer, make sure the software can recover APFS filesystems!).

If you were using macOS FileVault and its master key has been overwritten, it is going to be practically impossible to recover anything, as without the master key, the contents are indistinguishable from random data, and cracking the encryption is not a realistic possibility.

If the disk is a SSD and the installer executed a TRIM operation on the partitions it created as part of the installation, all your macOS data is now erased and gone.

The best and most reliable solution would be to restore from a Time Machine or other backup.

If you don't have a backup, and if your files would be worth more than about 500 USD to you, it might be best to **stop trying to do anything yourself** and contact some data recovery professionals.

If (and only if)

- you did not use FileVault or other disk encryption
- **and** the Kali installer did not do a TRIM operation on partitions it created

then it *may* still be possible to recover **some** of your files. Since the macOS partition is no longer there, I'm reasonably certain that at least some parts of it were overwritten, and so a restore from a backup or a reinstallation of macOS will be necessary to get macOS working again on this system.

Before reinstallation, you might want to try recovering your files with some Linux LiveCD that includes the [PhotoRec file recovery software](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec). You will also need another disk to which you can write any recovered files: "fixing" the partially-overwritten disk without a full restore or reinstallation is probably not a realistic option.

PhotoRec might not be the best software for the job (I'm not up to date on MacOS data recovery software) but at least it's free.

Comment: can you help me out in recovering this please?

Comment: The advice telcoM provided is that your data may be gone. Please update you question with: **if you have a Time Machine backup**, **if the disk is ssd/flash**, and **if you had FileVault enabled **. The last two, mean your data is gone. Restore from Time Machine.

Comment: No, I don't have time machine backup and filevault was disabled sir and the disk is APPLE SSD SM0512G Media